# IKVMC Runner Class

Tags: java, ikvm

I just created a JAR file that contains external dependencies in it so that I would just have one JAR file. I did this by using FatJar. When I did this my Jar worked fine, and I was able to run it with no problems. Then I used ikvm to convert my Jar to an exe. When I try to run the exe I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate 
>   com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot in the java.class.path: consider using
>   -Done-jar.jar.path to specify the one-jar filename

So the first thing I thought of was to check if there was a Manifest file that specified the classpath. There was indeed a Manifest file and this was it's contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 Created-By: Fat Jar/One-JAR Eclipse Plug-In
Main-Class: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot
```

I'm assuming this is correct because I'm able to run the JAR fine, and this was also created by FatJar.

I'm not really sure what to do next, and I'm not sure what -Done-jar.jar.path is. Anyone have a clue of what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the ikvmc compiler isn't seeing the JAR files embedded within the single executable JAR file you are creating.

You probably want to treat the creation of a single executable JAR file and the creation of a single Windows exe as separate processes. The Fat Jar plugin will create an executable JAR for you with no problems.

To create a Windows exe you'll probably need a batch file or ant script which invokes ikvmc on your code, and all of the JAR dependencies. I think you can provide a list of JAR files to convert on the ikvmc command line, and tell it to produce a single exe as its output. This will probably give you what you want!